# debugging go with gdb - log.Println stops gdb

Tags: go, gdb

When I debug with gdb and hit a line with log.Println("WhatEver")

gdb is just on a new blank line. How do I get back to gdb?

Thanks

Comment: How do you build your program?

Comment: go build -gcflags "-N -l" server.go